# debug iOS 8 device with Xcode 5.1.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Am I able to debug using my device, which I just updated to iOS 8? I want to keep using Xcode 5.1.1 if possible, but after updating the device I don't see it in the schema anymore (replaced by "iOS device" placeholder)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot build to a device running iOS 8 using Xcode versions prior to Xcode 6.0 because Xcode won't recognize the OS on your device. To test on iOS 8 devices, you can use Xcode 6 GM (since Xcode 6 isn't out yet on the App Store).

Download Xcode 6 GM in the [Apple Developer Member Center](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action).

**EDIT**

Per @rmaddy's comment, you *can* use Xcode 5 to test your app on an iOS 8 device (provided it doesn't use code only compatible with iOS 8+), but you **must** plug the device in once while running Xcode 6+ and allow it to process the symbol files from your device (you can view this in Xcode's Organizer). Then it should work with Xcode 5.

Comment: This is false. You certainly can use Xcode 5 to test an iOS 7 app on an iOS 8 device.

Comment: I was doing it all through the beta period over the last few months. It does require one initial trick. You do need to use Xcode 6 with the iOS 8 device once. Then it will work with Xcode 5.

Comment: @rmaddy Oh, that explains the issue then. Xcode 5 must just not initially recognize the symbol files, but once Xcode 6 processes them I guess it resolves the issue in Xcode 5. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Not sure about that. In the end, you really should just install Xcode 6 so you're up to date and everything runs as it should.

Comment: Ok, I was able to install Xcode 6 side by side with Xcode 5, and running the project in 6 did not alter the project file, so it was simple to run it -> get the symbols updated -> resume debugging in 5